# if $(3,5)$ belongs to $\{2,6\} \times \{ x, 8\}$ then $x=$?

Tags: functions

is this question **correct** ? if it is , what is the correct answer?

**what i think is that :**
the question is wrong as the first set has to have 3 in order for it to appear as a first projection in the ordered pair $(3,5)$

Comment: You are right. $(3,5) \not\in \{2,6\}\times \{x,8\}$ because $3\not\in \{2,6\}$

Comment: Please, learn to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type the math in your questions.

Comment: thanks @jjagmath

Comment: Also, from [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): **Your question should be clear without the title**. After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: Technically, $x$ can be *anything*. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth